# Can we determine if a filter is butterworth or chebyshev from its physical topology?

Tags: capacitor, analog, filter, inductor

Can all analog filters be classified as Bessel, Elliptic, Butterworth or Chebyshev?

Given a physical ladder topology of several stages of {L, C or LC} in {series or parallel}, is it possible to always classify it to one of the above?

(I got this question while trying to design a steep filter by trial and error on spice, and then realized that it has too long response, as a Chebyshev filter would have, so I wanted to optimize it.)

Comment: The topology tells you the order. The classification depends on the Q which depends on the component values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no. The 4 you mention are cornerstones of a myriad of subtley different and unnamed filters that occupy the gaps between those cornerstones. Not just that there are four cornerstones - there are other "named" types too.

See [gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter), [legendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimum_%22L%22_filter) and [Linkwitz–Riley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkwitz%E2%80%93Riley_filter) to see a couple more. There are even two types of Chebyshev filter (type 1 and 2). There's even an inverse chebyshev. There's probably a few more but the subtle ways that one filter can morph into another named type still leaves a lot of gaps.

The named filter types are not just arbitrary - there is some facet of the filter that is embodied in some mathematical ratio or value that is important in distinguishing it from others. Butterworth of course is probably the most obvious - maximally flat pass-band, overall damping ratio of 0.7071 and poles placed at equal angles.

Comment: Bessel may be less common that Butterworth, but its uniform phase response may be very important in some applications.  Is there useful respect in which a Butterworth filter is *qualitatively* different from what one would have if one arbitrarily changed some parameters slightly?

Comment: @supercat I guess making a real butterworth filter is impossible because it will be either not-maximally flat or have some passband ripple. However, if the intention is that a design is meant to be butterworth then that's good enough for me to define it as butterworth but, it may look like a butterworth but have some subtle mishapened response that is visible on close inspection and, if intended to be that way, would not make it butterworth. Bessel is important sure. They all are.

Comment: Andy aka, I know what you mean - however, I think this applies to ALL filters (because of tolerances and other uncertainties). Example: Will Chebyshev response (0.1dB) have aripple of exactly 0.1 dB? No, of course not.